# Perl multiple optional parameters

Tags: perl

I have a perl submodule which has 3 parameters: $text,$color,$font
Out of these paramters, $color and $font are optional.

If I need to pass only $font without $color, how can it be done as perl will assign the font string to $color when shift is used.

Answer (score 7):

The usual solution for multiple optional parameters is to take a hash.

```
sub myfunction {
  my %options = @_;
  my ($text, $color, $font) = @options{qw(text color font)};
  ...
}
```

then you call it like this:

```
myfunction( font => 'font goes here', text => "Here's the text") # no color
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using hashes?

Comment: @user5485904 `foo('bar', undef, 'baz')`

Comment: @user5485904, why would you want to not use hashes?  Writing a Perl script without hashes is like writing a novel without using the letter ‘E’.

Comment: If you use positional parameters, you can use `undef` as a placeholder as @MattJacob said above, but then the caller has to know which order the parameters go in; the hash makes it very clear which value is which.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Getopt module.

```
use Getopt::Long;

#make options
my $text;
my $color;
my $font;

GetOptions('-text=s' => $text, '-color=s' => $color, '-font=s' => $font,);

unless ($text){
     die "No text arg provided";
}

#do something
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the question is about passing parameters into a function (`sub`) call, not about accepting command-line parameters.

Comment: Yes, passing parameters to function.